# WordPress How to get fast Ajax when button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using " [Post Like System](https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System)" plugin, and I have this script below to make ajax happen when users clicking on the like button.

When I clicked the button, it takes 2 or 3 seconds to fill the heart icon+count.

So is there any way to fill heart icon and count before Ajax request?

Our users very angry for that delay :(

Note: I used Siteground hosting!

**simple-like.js**

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).on('click', '.sl-button', function () {
        var button = $(this);
        var post_id = button.attr('data-post-id');
        var security = button.attr('data-nonce');
        var iscomment = button.attr('data-iscomment');
        var allbuttons;
        if (iscomment === '1') { /* Comments can have same id */
            allbuttons = $('.sl-comment-button-' + post_id);
        } else {
            allbuttons = $('.sl-button-' + post_id);
        }
        var loader = allbuttons.next('#sl-loader');
        if (post_id !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: simpleLikes.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'process_simple_like',
                    post_id: post_id,
                    nonce: security,
                    is_comment: iscomment,
                    disabled : false
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    loader.html('&nbsp;<div class="loader">Loading...</div>');
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var icon = response.icon;
                    var count = response.count;
                    allbuttons.html(icon + count);
                    if (response.status === 'unliked') {
                        var like_text = simpleLikes.like;
                        allbuttons.prop('title', like_text);
                        allbuttons.removeClass('liked');
                    } else {
                        var unlike_text = simpleLikes.unlike;
                        allbuttons.prop('title', unlike_text);
                        allbuttons.addClass('liked');
                    }
                    loader.empty();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks @CristianoSoares for editing! btw, any help what that issue?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do it change button behavior without ajax and then send an ajax request.

For example, if the button has class liked, change it to "unliked" and then send an ajax request to unlike. If the button is "unliked", first set it to liked when user clicks it and then send an ajax request. Of course, this would mean that if ajax request fails your user won't be aware of it and won't know that their like action did not count, but instant button state refresh is worth it.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).on('click', '.sl-button', function () {
        var button = $(this);
        var post_id = button.attr('data-post-id');
        var security = button.attr('data-nonce');
        var iscomment = button.attr('data-iscomment');
        var allbuttons;
        if (iscomment === '1') { /* Comments can have same id */
            allbuttons = $('.sl-comment-button-' + post_id);
        } else {
            allbuttons = $('.sl-button-' + post_id);
        }

        // check if the button is liked, than mark it as unliked and vise versa
        if (allbuttons.hasClass('liked')) {
           var like_text = simpleLikes.like;
           allbuttons.prop('title', like_text);
           allbuttons.removeClass('liked');
        } else {
           var unlike_text = simpleLikes.unlike;
           allbuttons.prop('title', unlike_text);
           allbuttons.addClass('liked');
       }

        if (post_id !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: simpleLikes.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'process_simple_like',
                    post_id: post_id,
                    nonce: security,
                    is_comment: iscomment,
                    disabled : false
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, I appreciated your answer, but please I'm newbie with WP, Could you please give me an answer with my code above, Thank you!

Comment: Hey Adham. I have updated my answer with the code. I am not 100% sure it's bug or typo-free, because I have not tested but worth trying.

Comment: Nope, not working and i had a big problem now, button disappeared after click :(, and i back again to my original script but still disappearing, i cleared cache and browser cookie but still disappearing :(

Comment: Sorry to hear it's not working. Make sure you clear browser cache and hard reload the page after reverting to the previous version of the script. It's really hard to debug the issue without seeing the full picture.

Comment: Maybe i missed the hard reload, now it working again, Thanks, I guess our users now confused from disappearing button after click :))) 
This is one of my problems when i changed something users didn't feel about it!

Comment: @NickSurmanidze Can you tell me please what is different between `$(document).on('click', '.sl-button', function () {` and `$('.sl-button').on('click', function () {` because the second one does not work for me.

Comment: The first one always re-scans the document and searches for the button. For example, if a button is added dynamically after document is loaded you would use .on(). The second syntax is incorrect and instead of that you would use $('.sl-button').click(function() {...}) but in this case it will only search for that button on initial document DOM tree once and if the button will be added later with JS, for example, this button won't be found.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze So as the method you want to say, if we are in strict mode, it would be correct to do the button click with `$(document).on("click", ".abc", function () {` .